# Retrieve some information from WebLogic 10.3 internal keystore in a Java web application

Tags: java, weblogic, keystore

I need to get access on some information stored in the internal keystore used by WebLogic from a web application. 
Typically, I need to configure for a particular environment some user/password used to access another system from my web app, so I was thinking to store this in the server keystore.
I can't find any usable documentation on it so I guess if someone has ever done this.

Comment: Is your problem adding stuff to the keystore, retrieving stuff from it, or both?

Comment: Adding stuff in keystore is ok. My problem is to access this keystore from a webapp

Answer (score 0):

That is what the [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class is all about.
There are some similar questions around already. 
[java - how to store a key in keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894699/java-how-to-store-a-key-in-keystore)

Comment: My problem is : how to get a reference to weblogic keystore from my application deployed in the server